# What set of APIs count towards Firebase Auth API limits (500requests/second)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

The [firebase auth doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#api_limits) shows that you can only make Firebase Auth API calls up to 500 requests/second per service account & 1000 requests/second per project.

e.g. If I use Firebase Auth Admin SDK to invoke `getUserByEmail` or `updateUser`, do these operations count toward API limits?

How about verifying id tokens using `verifyIdToken` API? If my project verifies all requests coming in to the server from clients by verifying authIdToken, does that mean that my server's upper scaling threshold will be **1000 requests/second per project** because the server's one of downstream services, Firebase Auth, can only accept up to 1000 requests/second to verify auth id tokens?

Firebase doc seems to be lacking details related to these API limits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 1k/s includes all limits from the Admin API. I feel if the downstream can only handle 1k/s you can always implement a backoff or throttle algorithm to handle higher burst load at times. I assume these are mostly sufficient for user auth as user don't login frequently. For machine to machine, I suggest you use a different auth system.