# What are considered as API Limits in Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've read the docs about Firebase Auth Limits in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits. It states that there is a limit of 1000 requests/second per project. There is no example or any explanation about what those API Limits are. What kind of actions are counted in the API Limit? Does `verifyIdToken()` and `createUser()` in Admin SDK count as an API Request?

I am also aware that there is a duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928504/what-set-of-apis-count-towards-firebase-auth-api-limits-500requests-second) but it hasn't been answered well.

Comment: If the documentation is insufficient, you can reach out to Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Hello @DougStevenson, would it be possible to for you to tell us what things are considered as firebase auth limits here so that everyone can see it? Thank you. I would be reaching out to Firebase support directly if it isn't possible.

Comment: If I knew, I would have just said so.  Please contact support for a formal response.  When you get a response, you can post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Ok, thank you @DougStevenson. I'll post an answer here after contacting support.

Comment: @Uni you got any response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked Firebase Support about the API Limits and got the following response:

> The API’s quota applies depending on  the Firebase API you want to
> use. In this case the API quota applies to the use of the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth). Using it, you can query the Firebase Auth backend
> through a REST API. Also, it can be used for various operations such
> as creating new users, signing in existing ones and editing or
> deleting these users.
>
> To create, and refresh a token the quota will apply, if you use the
> REST API to do the operations. However, even if you don’t use the REST
> API there are other internal quotas associated with the refreshing of
> the token. In order to avoid refreshing the token so many times, set
> [forceRefresh](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) to **false** to minimize unneeded token refreshes when a
> valid token may still be cached.

I've also asked about the internal quota when refreshing the token using the official sdk and got this reponse:

> Unfortunately, some quotas are internal, and confidential information.
> For this reason, I am not able to share it with you. However, if you
> receive quota errors you can contact us

**The rate limit includes both the Client and Admin SDK:**

> The API limits encapsulates every request that comes from the API.
> This includes various operations such as creating new users, signing
> in existing ones, and editing or deleting users. The limits apply to
> requests coming from both the Client and Admin SDK. This means that
> Firebase allows you to have 1000 simultaneous requests/second (both
> from Client and Admin SDK) in a project.
> ~ Firebase Support